# Удаление/вставка/объединение массивов на C++

Tags: c++, qtcreator

После добавления цикла `while()` код начал плохо выполняться: при использовании функции 3 удаляется нужный элемент, но ещё и крайний, а если попытаться использовать после этого функцию объединения массивов 4, то вылетает консоль; если изначально использовать функцию 4 сначала, в дальнейших вызовах функций используется стартовый массив, а не тот, что получили после объединения.
Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
// Ф-ция заполнения массива числами
void fillArr(int* arr, int size, int d1, int d2);
// Сортировка массива
void sortArr(int* arr, int size);
// Вывод массива на консоль
void printArr(int* arr, int size, char* name);
// Поиск индекса
int findPos(int* arr, int size, int x);
void printFunc1(int* arr, int size);
// Вставка элемента в массив
void addToArr(int* arr, int size, int x);
void printFunc2(int* arr, int size);
// Удаление элемента с массива
void delFromArr(int* arr, int size, int x);
void printFunc3(int* arr, int size);
// Объединение массивов
void mergeArrs(int* arr, int* arr2, int size, int size2);
void printFunc4(int* arr, int size);
int main()
{
    int size, d1, d2;
    cout << "Enter the size of array: ";
    cin >> size;
    int *array = new int[size];
    int *arr=array;
    cout << "Enter limitation with using space: ";
    cin >> d1 >> d2;
    fillArr(arr, size, d1, d2);
    sortArr(arr, size);
    char* name = "Standart array: ";
    printArr(arr, size, name);
    while(True){
    char key;
        cout << "Choose function" << endl;
        cout << "1. Find element" << endl;
        cout << "2. Paste element in array" << endl;
        cout << "3. Delete element from array" << endl;
        cout << "4. Combining two arrays" << endl;
        cout << "\nFunction #";
        cin >> key;
        switch (key) {//вибір між функціями
        case'1':
            printFunc1(arr, size);
            break;
        case'2':
            printFunc2(arr, size);
            break;
        case'3':
            printFunc3(arr, size);
            break;
        case'4':
            printFunc4(arr, size);
            break;
        }
    }
   delete[]arr;
}
void fillArr(int* arr, int size, int d1, int d2) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arr[i] = rand() % (d2 - d1) + d1;
}
void sortArr(int* arr, int size) {
    for (int k = 1; k < size; k++) {
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i - 1])
                swap(arr[i], arr[i - 1]);
        }
    }
}
void printArr(int* arr, int size, char* name) {
    cout << name << " " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}
int findPos(int* arr, int size, int x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (x == arr[i])
            return i;
}
void printFunc1(int* arr, int size) {
    int x;
    cout << "Enter any element from array: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Index - " << findPos(arr, size, x) << " (In order - " << findPos(arr, size, x) + 1 << ")" << endl;
}
void addToArr(int* arr, int size, int x) {
    int left = 0, right = size - 1;
    while (left <= right) {
        int pos = (right + left) / 2;
        if (x > arr[pos])
            right = pos - 1;
        else left = pos + 1;
    }
    int i;
    for (i = size; i > right; i--)
        arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
    arr[i + 1] = x;
}
void printFunc2(int* arr, int size) {
    int x;
    cout << "Enter element for pasting: ";
    cin >> x;
    addToArr(arr, size, x);
    size++;
    char* name = "New array: ";
    printArr(arr, size, name);
}
void delFromArr(int* arr, int size, int x) {
    int pos = findPos(arr, size, x);
    for (int i = pos; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
    }
}
void printFunc3(int* arr, int size) {
    int x;
    cout << "Enter any element fro array to delete ";
    cin >> x;
    delFromArr(arr, size, x);
    size--;
    char* name = "New array: ";
    printArr(arr, size, name);
}
void mergeArrs(int *arr, int *arr2, int size, int size2){
    int newSize = size+size2, i=0, j=0, k=0;
    int *newArr = new int[newSize];
    int *arr1=newArr;
    while(i<size && j<size2){
        if(arr[i]>arr2[j])
            newArr[k++]=arr[i++];
        else newArr[k++]=arr2[j++];
    }
    for(i=i; i<size; i++, k++)
        newArr[k]=arr[i];
    for(j=j; j<size2; j++, k++)
        newArr[k]=arr2[j];
    char* name = "Completed array: ";
    printArr(arr1,newSize,name);

}
void printFunc4(int* arr, int size) {
    int size2, d1, d2;
    cout << "Enter size of second array: ";
    cin >> size2;
    int *array2 = new int[size2];
    int *arr2=array2;
    cout << "Enter limitation:  ";
    cin >> d1 >> d2;
    fillArr(arr2, size2, d1, d2);
    sortArr(arr2, size2);
    char* name = "Standar array 2: ";
    printArr(arr2, size2, name);
    mergeArrs(arr, arr2, size, size2);
}
```

Заранее спаибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, что отмечу: вместо char* намного лучше, удобнее и полезнее использовать string. Просто поменяйте char* на string и всё.

Далее по вопросу, в вашей функции delFromArr вы делаете это

```
for (int i = pos; i < size; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
```

но как я понимаю, вы хотите именно удалить элемент из массива, а не заменить с определённой позиции элементы на предыдущие, так как именно это и выполняет функция.

Лучше используйте это:

```
void dell(int*& arr, int size, int x) {
    int pos = findPos(arr, size, x);
    int* arr2 = new int[size-1];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < size; i++, j++) {
        if (i == pos)
            i++;
        arr2[j] = arr[i];
    }
    arr = arr2;
}
```

Надеюсь вопрос был мною понят правильно и ответ будет полезен.

Comment: благодарю за ответ! немного не понимаю как работать с *& и как с им потом обращаться в коде, буду признательна за объяснение

Comment: оператор *& передаёт в функцию сам объект, а не его копию, поэтому когда мы используем *& в функции, функция обрабатывает этот объект. 
Возможно я объясняю это не очень понятно, потому что для меня это тоже сложно для понимания, но советую урок по ссылке: https://ravesli.com/urok-80-ukazateli-vvedenie/#toc-0

Comment: спасибо за ответ!